# Por qué un script de JS no funciona regularmente?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Me pasa algo muy curioso con un `script` de `JavaScript` que se los voy a contar a continuación, esté `script` debe verificar si existen notificaciones sin leer y mostrar la cantidad que hay (1,2,3,n) o encuentre (sin leer aún), lo hace bien, pero cuando van 3 veces de estar en ejecución (realizando peticiones a la `BD`) o más deja de funcionar correctamente (no muestra notificaciones), la verdad no se que pasa ahí, lo he revisado y no tengo la menor idea, por eso planteó esta pregunta a ver si me ayudan.

Dejo el `script`.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){  

  load_unseen_notification();

  setInterval(function(){ 
  load_unseen_notification(); 
 }, 15000); 
  
 function load_unseen_notification(view = '')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"see-notification.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{view:view},
   dataType:"json",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('.count').html(data.unseen_notification);    
   }
  });
 }  
  
 $(document).on('click', '.nav-link', function(){
  $('.count').html(data);
  load_unseen_notification('si');
 });

});
</script>
```

En está parte pinto o muestro las notificaciones, aclaro que el `onclick` que hay, es porque al clickear allí me despliega o muestra las notificaciones con nombre y mensaje.

```html
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="notification-icon" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" onclick="notificaciones()">Notificaciones <span class="badge badge-light count" id="notification-count"> </span></a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
              <a id="info"></a>
              </div>
          </li>
```

Y el archivo `PHP` es una simple consulta que verifica sí están las notificaciones sin leer, pregunta si el `view` va vacío por `POST` y realiza la consulta, realizo un `count` para contar la cantidad sin leer y envío un `json_encode($data)`. Esto lo hace bien porque como les conté anteriormente me realiza el `script` bien por un tiempo.

**Nueva información**: les comparto que realice algo más pequeño como esto:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#datacount").load("see-notification.php");
        setInterval(function(){
            $("#datacount").load('see-notification')
        }, 15000);
    });
</script>
```

Y me hizo igualmente como el otro (trabajo tres veces bien), pero me fije que no esta llamando más al archivo PHP (también lo edite para este nuevo script) cuando deja de funcionar correctamente, el ajax no lo requiere o no lo ocupa más.

Les agradezco, espero ser claro, cualquier inquietud me lo hacen saber.

Comment: podrias validar que `data.unseen_notification` no este vacio y colocar un condicional  que ejecute  `data.unseen_notification` esta definida o existe! y hacer un `return 1;` para finalizar la funcion

Comment: Usa Sockets no ajax para manejar notificaciones en tu web aqui un enlace https://www.html5rocks.com/es/tutorials/websockets/basics/

Comment: Hola, gracias por la sugerencia, revisare este tema, también aclaro el archivo que pide el ajax realiza una consulta para mostrar el número de registros que no son leidos (aparezcan en 1), para realizar un count, lo raro es que después de cierto tiempo deja de realizar la petición al PHP. Gracias

Comment: Para montar un sistema de notificaciones push también puedes echarle un ojo a: https://onesignal.com/ Es una API muy completa con soporte multiplatform que te permite gestionar todo este tema. Tienen una amplia y buena documentación. De este modo, aparte de no tenerte que preocupar de desarrollar las funcionalidades básicas requeridas para el control de notificaciones, te aseguras de que funciona.

Comment: Hola Marc, iré a revisar este tema, porque aún estoy mirando, estoy con el tema de long polling probandolo. Gracias.